# Edit Comment Template in Netbeans PHP 6.8

Tags: php, ide, netbeans, netbeans6.8

I would like to ask is there any way change the comment code template in Netbeans PHP 6.8

In eclipse, when I type /** ENTER , it would come out the comment template that I set in the setting, like this:

```
/**
* Apr 19, 2010 - Shiro
* Description
*
* @return unknown_type
*/
function test()
{

}
```

by Default Netbeans only will show the parameter in the function.

```
/**
  *
  * @param <type> $order_No
  * @param <type> $array 
  */
```

in Netbeans is there any possible I could found any customization about this, anyone know where is the setting for this?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this for Netbeans PHP 6.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some way I feel NetBeans is just doing it *right* - Eclipse seems to mimic a "poor man's version control". But there are tons of free VCS, so why bother?

Comment: This is our company practise, we want to keep track who is the guy make the changes, easy to follow up with. I do know VCS can do the same thing, but we need to go to see the log, and check the which version and which guy make this change.

Comment: I know these "company practice" rules... My point is just that a VCS keeps track of exactly the information you need, and you get all this for free. I once had an NetBeans plugin running which added a small badge to every single line of code and when you hovered the pointer over this, it displayed who and when last modified this line. It was pretty neat. Maybe it is possible to think about this company rule, possibly it would be a change for the better.

Answer (score 3):

You go to menu:

Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates

You can select language: PHP

You'll have a list of the code templates that you can customize to your needs.

Comment: yup, this one I need to create a custom one, I cannot find any template link with /* {ENTER}