# Netbeans 8 auto add author to method comment

Tags: netbeans, documentation, comments

When I type a methods and generate comments via /** enter. 
It generates comment like this.

```
/**
* @param int $weight
* @return \KT_Forbes_Theme_Model
*/
```

Is the a possibility to auto add @author ?

```
/**
* @author A good guy
* @param int $weight
* @return \KT_Forbes_Theme_Model
*/
```

I have to add the @autor manualy for all the method, it is really anoing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible in current NetBeans versions as reported in https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251426. Also there are some related posts about this issue [Modify command / template for function commenting in NetBeans. Triggering with "/** + Enter key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592519/modify-command-template-for-function-commenting-in-netbeans-triggering-with/29251964?noredirect=1#comment46721852_29251964) or [Edit Comment Template in Netbeans PHP 6.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664934/edit-comment-template-in-netbeans-php-6-8?lq=1) (this last one does not solve the issue - at least in NetBeans 8.1).

I'm currently fighting with the IDE to include the auto comments with some data cause the comment added looks like:

```
/**
 *
 */
```

whitout any info included.

Answer (score 0):

This output is given typically for void methods, with no parameters.  
i.e.  public void parameterMapping()

For methods that have parameters and a return value should look like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @param parameter
 * @return
 */
private ASTNode recursiveParameterParser(ASTNode parameter)
```